# Statistics - relationships of 2 categorical variables

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

So my research question is: is there any factors that predicts whether you injure your dominant or non-dominant shoulder?

So a list of possible independent variables are gender (male/female), presence of diabetes (yes/no), injections (yes/no) etc.

So how do I work out the relationship of multiple independent variables combined to the dependent variable?
I have worked out their individual relationships.
What statistical tests should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linear regression](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linreg.htm) is what you need. Specifically, you are looking to do [regression with multiple categorical variables](https://psychstat3.missouristate.edu/Documents/MultiBook3/Mlt07.htm). [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance), or analysis of variance, will help you better understand the influence/effect of each independent variables on the dependent variable.